# What can you do with server-side includes & htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, server-side-includes

this issue just did not make sense to me, perhaps someone smart can help?
why is it that many hosts do not allow you to set htaccess or server-side includes?
specifically alot of the free hosting plans do not allow this, what are some situations that they are thinking of that makes them disable these features?

Answer (score 0):

Income - You're not paying anything, the only money they get are from advertisements.

Resources - they take up additional resources.  Offering only the essentials reduces the amount of risk and maintenance.

Agreement violations / unethical practices - It may reduce the amount of people signing up for free accounts to redirect websites, rename, hog resources, etc.

That's just what comes to mind.

Comment: what i mean is I am not sure what these do exactly? what can editing htaccess or server-side includes do that i cannot do already, as i can already redirect/rename ect. without it?

Comment: sorry for the english, not my native lang

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this as well, but one thing you can do with SSI is to make your web page design a lot easier.

You can seperate headers, footers, and nav divisions (or any HTML elements that are on every page of your site) into their own HTML files.  This means that when you add a page, or change one of those elements you only have to change them once, and then ensure they are included with an SSI include command into the correct spot on every page, nearly eliminating the chance of mistakes when putting the same element on every page.

SSI basically writes the referenced html file directly into the page wherever the include statement sits.

I know a lot less about .htaccess because I haven't played with it yet, but you can change which pages the server looks for SSI code in using different configuration commands.  It also looks like you can enable SSI.

I know there is a lot more to all this than I wrote here, but hopefully this gives you an idea.

Here is a website that probably better explains this: http://www.perlscriptsjavascripts.com/tutorials/howto/ssi.html